# Performing Calculations on Tuples Contained in a Text File

Tags: python, text, tuples

I have a text file that contains data. A snippet of the text file looks like this:

```
d1: p,h,t,m= 74.15 18 6 0.1 ign: 0.0003
 d2: p,h,t,m= 54. 378 -0.14 0.1 ign: 0.0009
d1: p,h,t,m= 715 8 16 0.1 ign: 0.0003
 d2: p,h,t,m= 50 78 4 0.1 ign: 0.0009
```

(where there is a space before d2). The text file contains several hundred lines.

What I am trying to do is extract the data from d1 and d2 like:

```
p = 74.15
t = 18
```

etc
I have done this by creating a dictionary. 
Then, I want to perform a calculation on the data as such, for example,

```
p (from d1)* p(d2) + t(from d1)
```

and repeat the calculation throughout the txt file.

Here is the code I have:

```
import math
with open("d.txt") as fp: # Opens the file

    data ={} #final dictionary
    line = fp.readline() # Read the file's first line

    while line: #continues to end of file

        name, _,cont = line.partition(":")#separates m1 from pt, eta, phi, m =..."
    #print(cont)
        numbers, _,ignore = cont.partition("dptinv") #separates dptinv from pt, eta, phi, m =..."
    #print(numbers) #prints tuple assignment needed
        keys, _,values = numbers.partition("=")
    #print(keys) #prints pt, eta, phi, m
    #print(values) #prints values (all numbers after =)
        key = [k for k in keys.split(",")]
        value = [v for v in values.strip().split(" ")]
    #print(key) #prints pt, eta, phi, m
    #print(value)
        thisdict = {}
        for k, v in zip(key, value): #creating an empty dictionary to fill with keys and values
            #thisdict[k] = v
            #print(thisdict)
        #data[name]=thisdict        
            line = fp.readline()#read next lines
            thisdict[k] = v
            data[name]=thisdict
            print(thisdict)

        #if " m2" in thisdict:
           #print("Yes")


#print(data)       

    #mul_p = float(data["m1"][" pt"])*float(data["m1"]["eta"])
    m = math.cosh(float(data[" m2"]["eta"])) * float(data["m1"][" pt"])
   #m1 = float(data["m1"][" pt"]) * float(2)
    print(m)
```

I had the code made from a combination of answers from my previous question on this, BUT...

1. One problem is: that the while loop reads through the entire file except the last two lines.

   d1:...

   d2:...
2. The second problem is that it seems like it is not reading the d2 data lines (or the line = fp.readline #read next lines is not doing anything), because when I try to calculate m , I get the error 
   Traceback (most recent call last): File "read.py", line 37, in m = math.cosh(float(data[" m2"]["eta"])) * float(data["m1"][" pt"]) KeyError: ' m2'

I asked about this from another forum and I am still trying to understand what is WRONG with HOW I wrote the code. And what do I need to do to fix it? Any help and guidance is much appreciated! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

you should try reorganize your reading process
and use more readable data structure

as far as i can see, 
data in your text file are grouped in paired lines ,
so my suggested process on this would be

```
# do your init outside of the loop
# 4 lists should have same length 
d1p =[] 
d2p= []
d1t= []
d2t= []
with open("muonsdata.txt") as fp: # Opens the file
    d1line = fp.readline() # Read one line supposed to have d1 
    d2line = fp.readline() # Read second line supposed to have d2
    # do more split staff
    # extract numbers and append to the associate list

for i in range(0..lens(d1p)):
    m=d1p[i]*d2p[i]+d1t[i]
```